# hide/show applications from taskbar in Windows with C#

Tags: c#, winapi, taskbar

I use the following code to hide from the taskbar...

```
private const int SW_HIDE = 0x00;
private const int SW_SHOW = 0x05;
private const int WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x40000;
private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -0x14;
private const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x0080;

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
bool isShow = true;
private void toggle(Process p)
{
    if (isShow)
    {
        isShow = false;
        SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE);
        //Hide: working

    }
    else
    {
        isShow = true;
        SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOW);
        //Show: not working
    }
}
```

But now I want the taskbar to show my program again - anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Can we see the code that invokes the toggle method?

Answer (score 4):

By calling `SetWindowLong` with the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` parameter, you're not setting or removing the flag, you're replacing the extended style completely with `WS_EX_APPWINDOW`. You might not notice it as you're not using any other extended styles.

The correct way of adding a style flag with `SetWindowLong` is:

```
SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, 
    GetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
```

The correct way of removing a flag is:

```
SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, 
    GetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
```

Read about bitwise operations to understand why that's the correct way of doing it.

As a side note, your way of hiding a window from the taskbar is quite bad. First of all, `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` doesn't only hide the button from the taskbar, but also changes the window border style. Also, you're hiding and reshowing the window, without a good reason.

The correct way of hiding a button from the taskbar is by using the [ITaskbarList::DeleteTab method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).